# Setting Checbox values in checkboxselectionmodel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I want a grid with checkbox in all rows like the one in this link http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#checkboxSelectionGrid After saving selected records, i want to set the checbox selected earlier.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid.getSelectionModel().select()` should work http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-select

Just pass array of record or their indexes you want to select. What seems to be a problem?